# Redirect script

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

currently, I'm redirecting users after x seconds to another page, but what I want to do is, redirect users after y seconds and the timer will start only after user click a link on my page, currently the timer starts only after the user visit my page.

Here is the code I found doing google search -

---

```
<head>
<script>
function js_wait()
{
setTimeout (js_go(), 3000); // 3000 ms = 3 secs
}
function js_go()
{
window.location = "mynexpage.php";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" onclick="js_wait(); return false;">My link</a>
</body>
```

- The body shows a link
- On click, it calls the javascript function "js_wait"
- js_wait starts a timer for x seconds, then calls js_go
- js_go redirects to the page.

---

I was able to make it redirect onclick but it redirects immediately after clicking the link, but I want it to wait y seconds before redirecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont activate the method instead just pass the function signature like this:

```
<head>
<script>
function js_wait()
{
setTimeout (js_go, 3000); // 3000 ms = 3 secs
}
function js_go()
{
window.location = "mynexpage.php";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" onclick="js_wait(); return false;">My link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay..thanks, Its working perfect...but one more help. <a href="" onclick="js_wait(); return false;" target="_blank">My link</a> should open in new window..but its opening in same window. Please help a bit more.

Comment: you need to create a window. you can see how to do it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Answer (score 5):

Remove `()` from setTimeout function parameter.

```
setTimeout (js_go, 3000); // 3000 ms = 3 secs
```

If you have it there, it means you pass the result of the function call rather then the function reference.

---

As background information, setTimeout can be used in two different ways: either you pass it a function reference, like what you have done, or you pass a string, which will be evaluated by the time setTimeout fires. This means that if you want to pass some parameters to setTimeout, you'd either pass them as a string (like `setTimeout('js_go("http://google.fi")', 3000)`) or wrap them to a function, which is the preferred way (`setTimeout(function() {js_go("http://google.fi")}, 3000)`).

However, since you don't use parameters here, you should just pass the function reference like shown in the code block above.

Answer (score 3):

Try this please much simpler: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FE4cT/

For redirect this is key: `window.parent.location`

Rest I hope it will fit your need `:)`

**code**

```
function js_wait() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.parent.location = "http://www.google.com";
    }, 3000);

}​
```

*Sample*

```
 window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }, 3000);
```

i.e. in your specific case:

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
            window.location = 'mynexpage.php';
        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write as :

```
    function js_wait_redirect() {
      setTimeout(
           function(){
              window.location = "mynexpage.php";
           }
           , 3000); // 3000 ms = 3 secs
    }
```